# Error al importar js en webpack (vue-cli)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex

[image: This dependency was not found]

Al intentar importar el script store.js me sale el error de la imagen.

**Estoy usando Vue-cli con Vue-router y Vuex.**

Es una instalacion limpia despues de instalar vue-cli instale vuex.

esto es el archivo de configuracion de webpack.base.conf.js

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

mi archivo store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
})
```

mi archivo main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from '/store'
//console.log(store)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

[image: Estructura del proyecto e instalacion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi los errores:

Uno era la forma en que lo estaba exportando y el otro error era la forma en que lo importaba.

**store.js** La exportacion

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
    export default new Vuex.Store({ //corregesta linea
      state: {
        count: 0
      },
      mutations: {
        increment: state => state.count++,
        decrement: state => state.count--
      }
    })
```

**main.js**
Faltaba un punto.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store' //CORREGI ESTA LINEA
//console.log(store)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```